# Codeigniter not working properly when hosted

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, localhost, hosting

I had developed a website using Codeigniter. It was working good in localhost. When i hosted it and clicked on links i get **"Internal Server Error"**.

Also i'm not able to see .htaccess files. Please tell me what i'm missing.

**Works perfectly**

Localhost:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site/';

<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/page') ?>"> Welcome </a>
```

When clicked above link, it goes to below url and works perfectly

```
http://localhost/site/welcome/page
```

**Hosted**

**Public Web Server (Error):**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mysite.com/';

<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/page') ?>"> Welcome </a>
```

When clicked above link, it goes to below url and gives an error

```
http://mysite.com/welcome/page
```

Comment: try loading this url on hosted server `http://mysite.com/index.php/welcome/page` If it works then, you haven't enabled rewrite module on server for htaccess to properly work..I can explain that if needed

Comment: Check on your htaccess file if you have included the `site/` part of the mod_rewrite to avoid the `index.php/`. If you find it, then remove it

Comment: if your site is hosted on `IIS` then you will need `web.config` file instead of `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/page') ?>"> Welcome </a>`

see docs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

OR *to hide `index.php`*

add .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Apache error logs check those for why you are getting the 'Internal Server Error.'

On a Linux server those are usually found in '/var/log/apache2/error.log.'

On a Windows server they can by default be found in something like 'C:\Program Files\Apache\logs.' Or you can find out the location by looking in the conf file or virtual hosts conf file if you use that.